# Parallelise a multi arguments python code over just one argument

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, arguments

I have a python function requiring 7 arguments:

```
my_fun(a,b,c,d,e,f,g)
```

I would like to run it in parallel, but keeping the arguments from b to g fixed and iterating over a.

The solution I found so far is to run it as a sub function:

```
def parallel_funct(t1):
    a = t1 
    b = list
    c = string
    d = list
    e= list
    f = list
    g = string
    stationxml_storage = string
    my_fun(a,b,c,d,e,f,g)
```

and I then run:

```
ts = np array

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(6)
    p.map(parallel_funct, ts)
```

Is there a way to do this using just my_fun?

Hope is clear

Answer (score 0):

The slightly more elegant way, avoiding to define a top-level function just for the sake of partial argument application, is to use the `functools.partial` function; but there's no way to tell `Pool.map` directly which argument you want to parallelize over.